# Is there any solution to embed "asx" to web audio player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html

I am trying to embed this link into a web player so I can customize it page.

http://asx.abacast.com/996_amman-radio-32.asx

is there anyway to embed it into radio streaming web player?

Comment: You deleted the old question, and posted a new one with the same 3 line layout? You're still going to get downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

The link you have posted is to an asx metadata file. These cannot be used as the source for any web player; they are for the Window Media Player to consume.

You could look inside the file. The streaming mount points noted in the file can be used as the source for an embedded Windows Media player, but this solution sucks because it will leave a blank space for platforms the don't support WMP (which is a lot).

If you are not the publisher/owner of this stream, it is generally considered to be bad form to embed it elsewhere.